# iPhone 7 has a cellular bug. Apple will repair - if i pay $$$ to have screen fixed too. Help!

Tags: iphone, cellular-carriers

iPhone 7 has a known bug that causes cellular service to sometimes fail - so the phone no longer works as a phone. 
Took phone with this bug into Genius bar, and was told they'd repair it for free - if I also agreed to have them repair a teeny crack in the screen for $150. They would not fix the cellular issue without the screen repair. 
Any ways around this?  Any way to get Apple to fix their bug for free?

Comment: I'm guessing Genius Bar employees are paid on commission, so by selling you an expensive repair they earn more money. Try going to another Apple Store and see if the employees there are any different, and report back here.

Comment: @Karin Do you have a link that details this known bug? - I have never heard of such known bug (doesn't sound like a bug from your description either, as those are due to software issues). If you're talking about a hardware repair of an antenna or similar, it sounds pretty standard that they won't repair other damages caused by yourself for free.

Comment: @jksoegaard The author didn't ask for that screen damage to be repaired.

Comment: @gparyani I know. The problem is that in order to replace for example a broken antenna, you'll need to open up the phone. If the screen is is already cracked, there's a high probability that the screen will be further damaged or even broken completely by the repair. I.e. you really want to replace the screen while you repair the other thing. This is why warranty repairs are usually only available for otherwise unharmed devices - you need to repair the cracked screen before you can repair the innards. I believe this is quite standard across cell phone makers.

Answer (score 3):

As alluded to in the comments, many hardware repairs require removing the screen. If the screen is damaged (no matter how minor) there's a very high risk of it shattering during the repair process, and that is why Apple (and many others) won't do a repair unless you're also getting the screen replaced at the same time.

As for your question on how to get around this, the only other option is to get the screen replaced somewhere else, or to try replacing it yourself. Then, once the screen is okay, Apple will perform the other repair as per normal.

**However, please note that not all screens are created equally and that the money you save on a non-genuine screen may not be worth it in the long run.** I've seen many cases of iPhones and iPads with non-genuine screens work just fine for a couple of months and then start to glitch like crazy.